# ssh connecting from macOS to ubuntu refused

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to connect to my PC (ubuntu) from my MacBook using ssh

When I run:

```
ssh leo@192.168.0.22
```

It connects. However if I try to use my public IP it says

> ssh: connect to host xx.x.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused

I have tried changing the port to port 2222 and the connection is still refused, only using the public IP address.

Comment: Please advise more about your network - where is the external address bound to? Where are you trying to connect from?  Are you familiar with the terms hairpin NAT and port forwarding- if so please speak to these in your post.

Comment: @davidgo This is a home network, I use ssh with my work network without issues but this seems to have problems, I am slightly familiar with hairpin NAT but not 100% sure so I don't want to give incorrect information to you

Comment: You really need to describe your network before we can help. It almost sounds to me like you need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Comment: @davidgo Do you want the topology of the network and I have updated the question with a possible fix

Comment: correction it did not fix

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if you are trying to connect from your LAN or WAN, the IP address you are connecting from, your subnet mask.  I'd also like to know if you have set up port forwarding on your router.